# cakephp3: Save associated data

Tags: php, conditional-statements, associations, cakephp-3.0

I want to write a easy Tagging-Plugin for cakephp3 applications. So lets say we have a model *books* and a model *reviews*. For each of this models it should be possible to attach Tags - just by adding a behavior (in a plugin): `$this->addBehavior('Tag.Taggable')`.

I created two Tables in the Database: `tags, tagged_tags`.

Table tagged_tags:

```
id  |  tag_id  |  tagged_id                   |
1   |  1       |  1                           |
2   |  2       |  1                           |
```

tagged_id is the id of the tagged entity. The information which model it belongs to is in the other table.
Table Tags:

```
id  |  tag     |  model                       |
1   |  book    |  App\Model\Table\BooksTable  |
2   |  nobook  |  App\Model\Table\ReviewsTable|
```

Obviously, only the first Tag belongs to a book.

```
class TaggableBehavior extends Behavior
{
    // Some more code here

    public function __construct(Table $table, array $config = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($table, $config);
        $this->_table = $table;

        $this->_table->belongsToMany('Tag.Tags', [ 
            'joinTable' => 'tagged_tags',
            'foreignKey' => 'tagged_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'conditions' => [
                'Tags.model' => get_class($this->_table);
            ]
        ]);

    }
}
```

Retrieving the data works perfectly. But saving is an issue:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'Tags.model' in 'where clause'
>
> SQL Query:
>
> SELECT TaggedTags.id AS `TaggedTags__id`, TaggedTags.tagged_id AS
> `TaggedTags__tagged_id`, TaggedTags.tag_id AS `TaggedTags__tag_id`
> FROM tagged_tags TaggedTags WHERE (tagged_id = :c0 AND Tags.model =
> :c1)

I'm not so sure why cakephp performs a SELECT-query here, and I don't really care. Why this query causes an error is clear. But where is my mistake here? It has to do with the `'conditions' => ['Tags.model' => get_class($this->_table);`. Without this, I can save data (but cant say which Tag belongs to a book or not)

**EDIT: Some Additional Info**

Here is the complete sql statement, displayed in the debug kit http://freetexthost.com/tc3s46nugi

controller code:

```
public function add()
{
    $book = $this->Books->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $book = $this->Books->patchEntity($book, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Books->save($book)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The book has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The book could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
```

In the Behavior I have some logic (copy/pasted) form the Bookmarks-tutorial

```
public function beforeSave($event, $entity, $options)
{
    if ($entity->tag_string) {
        $entity->tags = $this->_buildTags($entity->tag_string);
    }
}

protected function _buildTags($tagString)
{
    $new = array_unique(array_map('trim', explode(',', $tagString)));
    $out = [];
    $query = $this->_table->Tags->find()
        ->where([
            'Tags.tag IN' => $new,
            'Tags.model' => $this->name()
            ]);
    // Remove existing tags from the list of new tags.
    foreach ($query->extract('tag') as $existing) {
        $index = array_search($existing, $new);
        if ($index !== false) {
            unset($new[$index]);
        }
    }
    // Add existing tags.
    foreach ($query as $tag) {
        $tag['count'] = $tag['count']+1;
        $out[] = $tag;
    }
    // Add new tags.
    foreach ($new as $tag) {
        $out[] = $this->_table->Tags->newEntity(['tag' => $tag, 'model' => $this->name(), 'count' => 0]);
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your code that is in controller?

Comment: I've added the code to the posting above.

Comment: The Stack trace: http://freetexthost.com/3msbh4rabw

Answer (score 0):

Easy tagging plugin you will make if you create Tags model, and create a HABTM relationship with other models.

**Here are simple guidelines.**

*add.ctp*

Omit multiple select tags field, instead put tagging text field (eg. tagsinput). Add some jquery tagging plugin. When adding a new tag (keyword), it is immediately stored in the tags table via jquery post methods. If the keyword exists in the tags table, then do not store it again.

**Behavior**

In the beforeSave method processing value from tagging field.
If the value separated by a comma, you can use something like this (CakePHP 2):

```
public function beforeSave($options = array())
    {
        if(!empty($this->data['Article']['tagsinput'])) {
            $tags = explode(',', $this->data['Article']['tagsinput']);
            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                $tagKey = $this->Tag->find('first',array(
                    'recursive' => -1,
                    'fields' => array('id'),
                    'conditions' => array('Tag.name' => $tag)
                    ));
                $this->data['Tag']['Tag'][] = $tagKey['Tag']['id'];
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This creates HABTM relationship and stores such values in the table articles_tags.

*edit.ctp*

Create a comma separated values:

```
<?php
            $extract_tags = Hash::extract($this->data['Tag'],'{n}.name');
            $tags = implode(',', $extract_tags);
            echo $this->Form->input('tagsinput',
                array(
                    'id' => 'tags',
                    'div'=>true,
                    'label'=>__('Tags'),
                    'class'=>'form-control input-lg',
                    'placeholder'=>__('Add keywords here'),
                    'value' => $tags
                    )
                );
            ?>
```

Comment: Tagging works with my solution in principal. Even comma separated tagging style. The problem is saving the data with a condition in the belongsToMany methode.